# Re-size a view programatically Android

Tags: android, button, resize

I want to re-size a button, however I want it to be done over a specified period of time, for example: 5 seconds. I know how to resize the button, but not the time aspect. If the answer could be given programatically, rather than in XML, that would be fantastic!

Answer (score 0):

You can use an AsyncTask which runs for 5 seconds in the background and publishes progress (on the UI thread), for example every 0.1 seconds via onProgressUpdate(...) method.

Same can be achieved with Handler/HandlerThread.